# IF Statement with an AND Operator

Tags: orbeon

Hopefully this is a simple one..

Is it possible to have an "IF" statement with an "AND operator on a ***calculated value*** box:

[image]

I've tried various options without any luck, for example:

IF (AND ($Field1/string() = 'Completed'), ($Field2/string() = '')) then 'OK' else.

IF (AND ($Field1/string() = 'Completed', $Field2/string() = '') then 'OK' else.

if ($Field1/string() = '' and $Field2/string() = 'Completed') then 'true' else .

Also, can you use variables in these boxes (e.g. Var myFieldA)

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third exception expression looks correct:

```
if ($Field1/string() = '' and $Field2/string() = 'Completed')
then 'true' else .
```

The `if` must be in lowercase. Also `and` is an infix operator, as is the case in most languages, i.e. it isn't used as a function. Yes, you can access the value of other fields through variables, using the `$` syntax, but make sure that those names are correctly capitalized, as `$field` is different from `$Field`.

Comment: Many thanks Alex - didn't think of the upper/lower case distinction..